# Kendo UI Validator - TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'validate'

Tags: kendo-ui, validation

I'm using Kendo UI Web v2013.1.319 Validator and I have that error

> (TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'validate') only for validators with custom messages or rules.

For example, if I write:

```
var validator = jQuery('#name').kendoValidator({
    messages: {
        required: "Campo obbligatorio"
    }
});
```

I have that error when validator.validate(). If I write instead:

```
var validator = jQuery("#name").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");
```

I don't have that error when `validator.validate()`.
I have tried with jQuery 1.8.3, 1.9.1 and 2.0.2.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

See below examples:

This is an object therefore you can call validate on it. This is because you have called .data("kendoValidator") and stored the data part in a variable.

```
validator = $("#name").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");
```

This is not an object and therefore you cannon call validate() on it. Without calling the data("x"), the actual object exists but its not stored in your variable.

```
validator = $("#name").kendoValidator()
```

In your case, you need to do this:

```
var validator = jQuery('#name').kendoValidator({
    messages: {
        required: "Campo obbligatorio"
    }
}).data("kendoValidator");
```